# With clause subquery availablility for the entire SQL statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a SQL statement which reuses the subquery of the With clause multiple times in Oracle.

```
With mySubQ as (
    ...
) 

Select Something

From SomeTable, 
(
   Select *
   From mySubQ 
   where mySubQ.Something >= 0
) newSubQ

where mySubQ.Something = SomeTable.Something
```

This gives me error -  ORA-32034 unsupported use of WITH clause

What am I missing?

Comment: You need a comma between the subquery and `newSubQ`. But it would be better if you used ANSI JOIN syntax.

Comment: I dont understand. The newSubQ is just an alias for the SQL statements in the brackets right? Where are you suggesting I put a comma?

Comment: Sorry, I confused `newSubQ` with `mySubQ`.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to add the part where I was actually using the muSubQ. I hope this is more clear.

Comment: The WHERE clause in the outer query can't reference tables in a subquery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to join with `mySubQ`, not just define it.

```
WITH mySubQ AS (...)
SELECT Something
FROM SomeTable
JOIN mySubQ ON mySubQ.Something = SomeTable.Something
WHERE mySubQ.Something >= 0
```

If you put the query of `mySubQ` in a subquery, you can't reference `mySubQ` in the `WHERE` clause of the main query. Each level of query can only access tables in its own `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses, not those of subqueries.

Comment: What you have in the comments, (*"The WHERE clause in the outer query can't reference tables in a subquery"*), should be in your answer, too, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added a little more explanation of that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the error: `where mySubQ.Something = SomeTable.Something`.

The bottom query selects from `SomeTable` and from the subquery with alias `newSubQ`,
so `mySubQ.Something` is not known in this context.

If `something` is a real column name, not only a "placeholder in the pseudocode", then there is also another error here: `Select Something` - the column is ambiguous, because both `sometable` and the subquery have this column.

Try this query:

```
With mySubQ as (
    SELECT * FROM sometable
) 

Select newSubQ.Something

From SomeTable, 
(
   Select *
   From mySubQ 
   where mySubQ.Something >= 0
) newSubQ

where newSubQ.Something = SomeTable.Something
;
```

Demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/88855/12

This demo contains also another example of using `WITH` clause:

```
WITH mySubQ AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM sometable
),

mySubQ_1 AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM mySubQ
   WHERE somethingelse = 1
),

mySubQ_2 AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM mySubQ
   WHERE something between 2 AND 5
)

SELECT *
FROM sometable s, mySubQ_1 m1, 
     (
        SELECT * FROM mySubQ_2
        WHERE something < 10
      ) m2
WHERE s.something = m1.something
  AND m1.somethingelse = m2.somethingelse
```

Comment: I don't think he meant `Something` as the actual column names, he was writing pseudocode and that looks like a placeholder.